# React Content Security Policy (CSP) not loading the bundle files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, content-security-policy

I've implemented Content Security Policy (CSP) for my existing application with react and node . In the header I've added csp code like this `

-

```
'Content-Security-Policy', 'default-src \'self\' https; script-src
   \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; img-src \'self\' data: ; font-src
   \'self\' data: \https://fonts.googleapis.com\
   \https://fonts.gstatic.com\ ; style-src \'self\'
   \'sha256-rigr5uxAUhb5lEsRjTMBA5S2juuVOhHXstW+OjxdE+I=\'
   \'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=\'
   \'sha256-1tr38LWy83eluPFcuLQYtramGMCOjscxtiOqVJ/gMrc=\'
   \'sha256-XmRbDWO4PqwfNgeZPWi3/fHjRx02kfcTM8yid7tdHmw=\'
   \'sha256-ZAzabP7foNZKvX4PqkWVi1UH7ceqLrmDfa/nFYEjJFE=\'
   \'sha256-JTGGKTw77cKzHSmo5g2N94OEWo3dbzNZQ/yT2IqNKow=\'
   \'sha256-Bz44xM5KHxgdFnmpU755ZnbcU+V2yM+Ox5ljX4u+vVs=\' 
   https://fonts.googleapis.com; base-uri \'self\';form-action
   \'self\';'
```

I thought script-src : self will load the files of current domain of the application but it's not . For example here I don't see application working of script-src :self
[image]

only if I add `script-src : self http://localhost:6200/core.2d6b592992d851d11f4c.js http://localhost:6200/vendor.2d6b592992d851d11f4c.js http://localhost:6200/bundle.2d6b592992d851d11f4c.js`  it works

the application is bundled using webpack .

I've got two questions

1. Do we need to add the bundles in script-src even after giving script-src : self ? if yes the hash will be different for environments like stagging and production how can we handle that ?
2. can we use style-src : unsafe-inline ? or from that also script can be injected ?

any sort of explanation would be helpful !

Answer (score 1):

1. If 'self' is localhost, it may not cover localhost:6200. Also if you are on https, http will not be included. Try adding http://localhost:6200 to script-src for development.
2. See https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/

Comment: clear for 2 nd point ! regarding 1 st one I've tired with https too but still script-src self doesn't load the bundle files , I need to do something like this "https://domain/core.2d6b592992d851d11f4c.js"